# Preselect images of hyperoslo/ImagePicker

Tags: swift, uiimage, phasset

I got stuck with this. Maybe someone of you got an idea or solution for this.

The user can select Images through the ImagePicker and save them. When he later wants to change the selected images and opens the ImagePicker I want these images to be preselected. 
The selected Images are stored as UIImage (maybe better to change it to PHAsset or sth. else?)

It's not possible to hold a reference to the picker. Cause the user can have lots of different datasets with selected images.

The Image Picker is working with PHAsset. If it would be possible to fetch a PHAsset from the images data, I think it would solve this. But I found no way for it.

Here is the github link for the imagepicker: https://github.com/hyperoslo/ImagePicker

Comment: Did you have any luck with this?

Comment: Yeah I programmed my own one :D.

Comment: Okay, I was thinking of that to...